# Why shouldn't I prefix member variables in StyleCop?

Tags: c#, coding-style, stylecop

**StyleCop** just informed me that I shouldn't be prefixing member variables with `m_`. Is that the offical line on c# coding styles? I guess so as its from MS. Does anyone know anything about this??

> By default, StyleCop disallows the use of underscores, m_, etc., to mark local class fields, in favor of the ‘this.’ prefix. The advantage of using ‘this.’ is that it applies equally to all element types including methods, properties, etc., and not just fields, making all calls to class members instantly recognizable, regardless of which editor is being used to view the code. Another advantage is that it creates a quick, recognizable differentiation between instance members and static members, which will not be prefixed.

Comment: Yes, that is the official line... I don't have much to add really. I think the rule text that you supplied states the intent clearly.

Comment: time for a quick refactor then!!

Answer (score 5):

Though I do like a bit of `_` prefixing for private member fields. Simply to distinguish them by more than just case from corresponding getters/setters.

Comment: Amen to that. This will help avoid `private int myProp; public int MyProp { get { return MyProp; } }`

Comment: @erikkallen: Were I in charge of languages or coding styles, I would specify that declaration of an identifier in a given scope would disallow within that scope the use or declaration of variable that differed was different only in case.  If an outer scope declares X and an inner scope declares x, then within the inner scope, X wouldn't refer to the outer scope's variable (as in C#), nor the inner one (as in VB.NET), but to nothing.  I find it bizarre that people rail against Hungarian, but the use casing for the same purpose.

Comment: @supercat If I designed a programming language I would make it case insensitive (and also if I designed a file system).

Comment: @erikkallen: If a programming language does not allow identifiers which differ only in case, then utilities could quickly and easily correct the case of any mistyped identifiers.  Outside of "immediate mode" commands (which might silently be converted to proper case) I see no reason why a language should not require a source file to use correctly-cased identifiers.  If a class has a property `Foo` and a method has a local variable `foo`, I see no benefit to allowing `doSomething(Foo)` as a means of reading the local variable.  With regard to file systems...

Comment: ...there is no particularly good approach since some software is inconsistent with upper/lowercase usage, and other software relies upon the ability to create files whose names differ only in case.  The best approach would probably be to have a file attribute to say whether a file's name should be matched narrowly or broadly, have a directory attribute to specify the default behavior for files in that directory, and have inheritable thread-local 'file mode' to request particular behavior.  File names specified from a UI would not generally pose a problem; if a user asks to save a file as...

Comment: ...`someFile.txt` when a file `SomeFile.txt` already exists, a UI could prompt the user to ask what should happen.  In many cases, the optimal behavior for files might be to say that opening any variation of `somefile.txt` would work for reading, but operations that could create new files would fail unless the name either perfectly matched an existing name or was completely distinct; no single behavior would work in all cases, however.

Answer (score 5):

Bear in mind that **Style** Cop is a tool for enforcing *a particular* (in this case Microsoft's internal) coding *style*. Its recommendations should not be accorded the same weight as those of FxCop, or any other recommendations from the (excellent) Framework Design Guidelines book. The person or organisation that controls any given source code should be the source of the *style* guidelines for that code - there is no global 'official' coding style any more than there is an 'official' email signature or 'official' coding font.

Comment: The *official* coding style is *my* coding style.  Of course!

Answer (score 3):

It is all a matter of your style. You can go in and modify that rule to suit your coding style so you don't get annoyed by it. Personally I feel the m_ is a little verbose, "I already know it's a member!" I would just go with an underscore ex. _member.

Answer (score 2):

It you look at the section [Names of Type Members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229012.aspx) then it says:

> The field-naming guidelines apply to static public and protected
>   fields. **Internal and private fields are not covered by guideline**

(my emphasis)

I've always found it annoying that Stylecop likes a `this` prefix. It's instantly recognizable to me that I'm calling a class member because I'm saying:

```
Load();
```

and writing:

```
this.Load();
```

Doesn't really tell me much more, it just makes my line more verbose. Sure, `Load` could be static, but what do i care?

Personally I like the `m_` approach. It makes it easy for me to search through code for member variables, all the member variables group together in the member dropdown, and when I enter `m_` Intellisense immediately narrows the list down to all my member variables. You don't get any of this when using the `this` prefix.

If you run Reflector against the core C# libraries you'll see prefixes like `m_` and just `_` used, so clearly Microsoft are pretty flexible on the naming of private and internal members.

When I see code with `this` prefixs for member variables and methods I tend to lower my opinion of that developer, particulary if a conversation about it ends with them justifying it on the grounds that "Stylecop says I should".

Comment: I too don't like using "this.", but I have to - the gated builds reject stylecop errors so for me I do this because I have to due to the companies C# guidelines.

Comment: I'd upvote your if you were preferring using `_`, not `_m`.

Answer (score 0):

Naming conventions are documented here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0(VS.71).aspx

Hungarian notation is discouraged.